# Weird Python Lambda() syntax

Tags: python, pytorch

As below, I understand **lambda y:...** .

But the first **Lambda(...)** is a function?.

```
ds = datasets.FashionMNIST(
...
    target_transform=Lambda(lambda y: torch.zeros(10, dtype=torch.float).scatter_(0, torch.tensor(y), value=1))
)
```

Comment: `Lambda` is not defined in standard Python. Check imports for what is the source of `Lambda` method.

Comment: This is not Python built-in syntax.  It's just a function provided I guess by pytorch.  It's spelled `Lambda` with a capital `L` in order to not conflict with the Python keyword.

Comment: There is indeed a `Lambda` from pytorch: https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.Lambda.html
It is a class rather than plain function. Maybe you should check the import anyway just to be sure.

Comment: Assuming your import is correct, we can find the source in https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/_modules/torchvision/transforms/transforms.html#Lambda There is `class Lambda:` and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a function in [torchvision](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.Lambda.html) for wrapping an arbitrary function as a transform.  It's nothing to do with Python syntax, and is spelled `Lambda` with a capital `L` instead of `lambda` to not conflict with the Python keyword.

Comment: Yes, This is just function. a silly question